# .Net MVC5 Custom Model Binder for sub properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, handsontable

I have a HandsontableModelBinder. This binder will bind on the handsontable json serialized data from a single hidden control. I was previously binding on a list of hidden controls, it worked but performance when pasting a large excel sheet was terrible. Now performance is great except a [Required] validation attribute will not validate since the inner properties of this complex type are not really "binded". I bind them myself by deserializing the hidden control.

How would I go about binding/validating each inner property of my complex type?

```
public class UnitedHandsontableListModelBinder : UnitedBaseModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic list = Activator.CreateInstance(bindingContext.ModelType) as IList;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.AttemptedValue))
            list = serializer.Deserialize(value.AttemptedValue, bindingContext.ModelType);

        return ValidateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, list);
    }
}
```